# Froala Editor: get content and post ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, froala

I use

```
`$(".selector").editable("getHTML");`
```

Like document said to get content in HTML.

Example this is a content from method getHTML:

```
<p><b>Hello</b>, people</p>
```

Then I post ajax request to server to save the content, but the server doesn't response my request, if I change the content to:

```
`Hello, people`
```

by remove html tag, server response my request. So the problem come from I send message contain forbidden character.

How do I convert or wrap the content like submit form method does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try and it works:
1. I use getHTML to get content in HTML format.
2. Set text of textarea by the above content.
3. Get encode html by calling .html() from textarea. $('#selector').html();

Now I have string value will be accepted by server.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you pass it to server Maybe you should pass it as a string

```
var passToServer = (".selector").val();

       return $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(passToServer ),
                url: "/api/,
                contentType: "application/json"

            });
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thank for your comment, I found solution and I posted the answer.